# Should i use rss feed for my news app project?

Tags: android, json, api, rss, rss-reader

I am working  on a simple news app project in android for which i want to use different news api but someone told me to use rss feeds for more updated news. I think api is good option but I am still learning and don't know what to do now.

Comment: You should go with RSS feed reader.some of the reference app you can find here, which uses rss feeds to display updated news.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.forexlive
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.news.moneycontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to integrate popular newspaper news you should used rss feeder for your app. if you want to make it custom newspaper app going for api integration.

Comment: so i have to use rss feed for more updated news , am i right? but i want to show news in a single format.

Comment: yes, if you want to make it by rss feed please check below link https://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/02/simple-rss-reader-application-in-android.html

Comment: It's a good link. i want to ask how famous news apps like dailyhunt  and news dog app get so much updated news? Do they also use rss feeds?